# AWS Android SDK error while creating AmazonPollyPresigningClient - signerClass is null for AmazonPollyCustomPresigner

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

When I integrate Polly in my Android application, I am getting 'IllegalArgumentException' because in SignerFactory, Signer is null for signerType - AmazonPollyCustomPresigner. I am using AWS Lex and Polly in the same application. I am using 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-polly:2.4.2'. In the sample application provided by AWS, with the same credentials, Polly is working fine. In that they have used com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-polly:2.3.4. I cannot use it because I already interpreted 2.4.2 with other AWS technologies.

Comment: Fixed. I have added a ClientConfiguration like ClientConfiguration cf = new ClientConfiguration();
            cf.setSignerOverride("QueryStringSignerType"); and created AmazonPollyPresigningClient by passing the ClientConfiguration. I don't know whether this is the correct approach.

Comment: Setting the signer type didn't resolve the issue. I am getting invalid signer error while playing a text.

Comment: Are you using version 2.4.2 of core and polly?

Answer (score 0):

When I faced the same issue, changing the signer override corrected it.

`ClientConfiguration cf = new ClientConfiguration();
 cf.setSignerOverride("AWS4SignerType");`